# why copy constructor called but not move constructor in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is the C++ test I do. I thought move constructor would be called, but it's not. neither the two cases will call move constructure.

```
class MyTest
{
public:
    MyTest() {}
    ~MyTest() {}
    MyTest(const MyTest& lv) {}     // be called actually 
    MyTest(MyTest&& rv) {}          // not be called actually, but i thought would
    void operator=(const MyTest& lv) {
        MyTest(std::move(lr));      // i thought the move constructor would be called here
    }
};
int main()
{
    // case1:
    MyTest m1;
    MyTest m2 = m1;

    // case2:
    MyTest m3;
    MyTest m4;
    m4 = m3;       // move constructure will not be called either.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know? You didn't even give a body to the move constructor, and the bodies of the rest are empty...

Comment: i have fixed it

Comment: `MyTest(MyTest&& rv)` is an *rvalue* constructor. And `m1` isn't an rvalue.

Comment: `operator=` doesn't get invoked when initializing. The `operator=` is nonsensical on multiple levels (it receives a `const` ref named `lv`, and moves from a different variable named `lr`; if that's supposed to be `lv`, why do you think you can move from a `const` ref?). The "[MCVE]" doesn't even compile.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, but i move it in operator=

Comment: `MyTest m2 = m1;` isn't assignment, it's *initialization* and calls a constructor directly. It's equivalent to `MyTest m2(m1);`

Comment: i try like this：     MyTest m1;  MyTest m2;   m2 = m1;    the result is the same.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, i originally means  MyTest m1;  MyTest m2; m2 = m1;  it's a slip-up.

Comment: @yshi `m1` is an lvalue, so `m2 = m1` performs a *copy assignment*. To perform a *move assignment*, you need an rvalue instead on the right side. You can cast an lvalue to an rvalue using `std::move()`, eg: `m2 = std::move(m1);` But the code shown does not have a move assignment operator defined : `MyTest& operator=(MyTest&& lv)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *copy* assignment operator

```
void operator=(const MyTest& lv) {
    MyTest(std::move(lr));
}
```

have *three* problems:

1. The argument is named `lv` but you use `lr` inside the function;
2. The argument `lv` is a reference to a *constant* `MyTest` object, it can't be "moved" from;
3. And the statement

   ```
   MyTest(std::move(lv));  // Corrected the variable name
   ```

   doesn't make much sense on its own.

   It creates a *temporary* object by rvalue initialization. *But* since the object isn't used any more the compiler is free to optimize it away making the body of the assignment operator empty.

   If you look at the generated code you will most likely see the object creation missing.

Comment: thank you，your answer benefits me. And thanks for all !

Comment: @ Some programmer dude   OK !